# How can I remove the back decorative pattern for my OCR？

Tags: opencv, ocr, image-segmentation

[image]

I have try the `GaussianBlur` and `adaptiveThreshold`, but this kind of back decorative pattern troubles me a lot.

Can I try something else? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full code for the solution:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('test.png', 0)
img2 = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c)>50:
        cv2.drawContours(img2, c, -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

kernel = np.ones((40, 10), np.uint8)
img2 = cv2.morphologyEx(img2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("image", img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

First you should binarize the image using `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` and `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` methods. The result would be like this:

[image]

After that you should remove noises in the result image. For that what I did here is, I get contours of the image using `cv2.findContours` and calculated the `cv2.contourArea`. Then using a threshold filtered out small contours in order to remove noises. After that to combine eroded characters I performed `cv2.morphologyEx`.

Final result is like this:

[image]